# Resharper Quick Fix return Cursor

Tags: resharper

Is there a shortcut in Resharper to return your cursor to it's original location after applying a quick fix?  It would be very nice to be able to add a parameter to a method, enter the parameter name and then jump back to where you originally were to keep typing.  Or create a field/property and go back, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `ReSharper | Navigate | Previous Edit` or `ReSharper | Navigate | Resent Edits` for this goal. Or after creating a field/property, press `ReSharper | Find | Find Usages` and it will move the cursor to the place where you applied "Create from Usage" quickfix.

Comment: Unfortunately the "Previous Edit" doesn't work.  I'm not sure what this feature is tracking but even when I type a new method with no parameters, type "Console.Out.WriteLine(someVar);", hit save, then quickfix to generate "someVar" as a parameter, when I select "Previous Edit" which should take me to the "someVar" in the body, instead it jumps to some edit I made an hour ago.  I have the latest resharper so this seems broken to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio's Navigate Back command, which is `Ctrl+-` (ctrl and minus)

Comment: That's what I've been using but sometimes it does not take you back to where you were editing, but it will take you to the end of the line, or the end of the block you were in.  Kind of annoying because it's almost what I need so I figured maybe resharper had a better option.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Like the testing I'm doing now, navigate back keeps jumping back to a previous file instead of back to where I last did a quick fix.  Super frustrating.